# Size of a vertical bar symbol

Tags: amsmath, stix

I am using stix fonts to type a formula containing bra-ket notations from quantum mechanics. I observe that the size of a vertical bar is either too small:

[image]       `\big\}\lvert\psi\rangle` ,

or too large:

[image]       `\big\}\big\lvert\psi\big\rangle` .

I would like to make the `\lvert`and the `\rangle` symbols be of the same height as `\big\}`. Is it possible to achieve this somehow? For a reference I posting the full source:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}
  %===============================================
  \settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
  \setbinding{1cm} % space for binding
  \setlrmarginsandblock{*}{3cm}{1} % spine = edge. Edge=3cm
  \setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1} % upper=lower. Upper=3cm
  \checkandfixthelayout
  \pagestyle{empty}
  %===============================================
  \usepackage[]{stix,amsmath}
  %===============================================
  \begin{document}
  Compare different height of vertical bars here
  \begin{subequations}
  \begin{eqnarray}
  g(t-t')&=&-i\langle\psi\lvert T \bigl\{\hat c(t)\,\hat c^\dagger(t')\bigr\}\lvert\psi\rangle,\\
  g(t-t')&=&-i\langle\psi| T \bigl\{\hat c(t)\,\hat c^\dagger(t')\bigr\} |\psi\rangle;
  \end{eqnarray}
  \end{subequations}
  and  here
  \begin{subequations}
  \begin{eqnarray}
  g(t-t')&=&-i\bigl\langle\psi\bigr\rvert T \bigl\{\hat c(t)\,\hat c^\dagger(t')\bigr\}\bigl\lvert\psi\bigr\rangle,\\
  g(t-t')&=&-i\bigl\langle\psi\bigr| T \bigl\{\hat c(t)\,\hat c^\dagger(t')\bigr\}\bigl|\psi\bigr\rangle.
  \end{eqnarray}
  \end{subequations}
  and here $\big\}\big|\psi\big\rangle$.
\end{document}
```

and the full output:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please always post complete documents (as in the answers posted so far). Such problems are usually result of clashing package definitions and you have given no indication of which packages you are loading, in which order.

Comment: @ David Carlisle Thank you for this comment. I uploaded the full source and corresponding output. Interestingly, your solution does not work here (see last line).

Comment: Never ever use `eqnarray`.

Comment: Yes it's a clash with amsmath, you get the correct size with `\usepackage[]{stix}\def\lvert{|}\def\rvert{|}\def\subequations{}` I see @egreg has just posted with a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a bug in the STIX fonts, I'm afraid.

All delimiters I tried scale perfectly with `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`, whereas it doesn't happen with the vertical bar, for which `\big|` and `\Big|` produce the same size.

The `\delcode` of `|` with the STIX fonts is `"3F03F3` and the characters in `stix-mathex` have metrics

```
(CHARACTER O 360
   (CHARWD R 0.32)
   (CHARHT R 0.69)
   (CHARDP R 0.189)
   )

(CHARACTER O 363
   (CHARWD R 0.32)
   (CHARHT R 0.55)
   (VARCHAR
      (REP O 363)
      )
   )
```

to be compared with the metrics in the Computer Modern fonts when the delcode is `"26A30C`; first the normal variant in `cmsy10` that has

```
(CHARACTER O 152
   (CHARWD R 0.277779)
   (CHARHT R 0.75)
   (CHARDP R 0.25)
   )
```

and then the larger variant in `cmex10`

```
(CHARACTER O 14
   (CHARWD R 0.333334)
   (CHARDP R 0.600006)
   (VARCHAR
      (REP O 14)
      )
   )
```

As you can see, the *depth* is set, and not the height.

A workaround is to redefine `\big` in such a way that it adjusts the choice when `|` follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\amstexbig\big
\def\newbig#1{%
  \ifx#1|%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\big@bar}%
  {\amstexbig{#1}}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\big\newbig}
\def\big@bar{\bBigg@{1.1}|}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\}|\rangle$

$\big\}\big|\psi\big\rangle$.

$|\big|\Big|\bigg|\Bigg|$

$\{\big\{\Big\{\bigg\{\Bigg\{$

$(\big(\Big(\bigg(\Bigg($

$[\big[\Big[\bigg[\Bigg[$

\end{document}
```

Making it work with `\lvert` and `\rvert` would be possible, but requires pure expansion, so many layers of `\expandafter`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Looks like a magic. I've read the linked question, but still didn't understand. Could you, please, explain your answer. My concern is what will happen with other parts of my document due to such declaration.

Comment: @yarchik No, it doesn't really work; I'm working on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for me, even for \lvert. At the beginning of your answer you showed font matrices. I have to admit I never look there. How common is for people to have this knowledge? I am using latex/xetex almost daily, I pay a lot of attention to typography. However in my evolution I have not reach this point: in particular, low level tex commands I can decipher only slowly. How to get more proficiency in this direction, should one attempt to understand each line in your answer or it is better just to use it as it is?

Comment: @yarchik That's knowledge about the font metric files I acquired in several years' experience. Reading the appendices of the Metafontbook is necessary, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
$\big\}\big|\psi\big\rangle$

\end{document}
```

I got undefined command with `\lvert` using `|` the size seems correct to me:

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar choice of font designer, but is not 10% too big as shown in question

Comment: You need `amsmath` for `\lvert`. But recall that `amsmath` redefines `\big`.

Comment: @egreg I know, but I wanted the OP to show the order, yes I see from your answer that is the issue, although isn't clear what a general fix should be, the amsmath definition seems over sensitive to font changes.

Answer (score 0):

The [`braket`](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/braket/braket.pdf) package provides both small and expanding version of `\bra{}`, `\ket{}`, `\braket{}`, and `\set{}`. These should scale correctly (or at least uniformly).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
%===============================================
\usepackage[]{stix,amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\pagestyle{empty}
%===============================================
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
g(t-t')&=-i\langle\psi| T \bigl\{\hat c(t)\,\hat c^\dagger(t')\bigr\} |\psi\rangle\\
g(t-t')&=-i\Braket{\psi | T \Set{\hat c(t)\,\hat c^\dagger(t')} | \psi}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really better...