# intriguing stix commath conflict

Tags: packages, incompatibility, delimiters, stix, commath

I've encountered a curious issue with `commath` and `stix` the cause of which I do not understand.  Consider

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{stix}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \Biggl\{\biggl\{\Bigl\{\bigl\{\{  \qquad  \text{stix, commath}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following output, depending on which combination of packages is included.  Notice `\big\{` versus `\Big\{` (third and fourth symbol).  In short, stix and commath appear not to work together nicely.  What is the cause of this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know how to fix the problem using a solution for a different problem found [elsewhere.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227466/size-of-a-vertical-bar-symbol)  But what can cause the bug I'm describing here?

Comment: Since `commath` is essentially a collection of bugs, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: just don't load commath

Comment: Now those are ringing endorsements!  