# Spacing between bars in textstyle fractions--issue with STIX2 or OpenType Math specification

Tags: fractions, opentype, stix

Given the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    \frac12\textstyle\frac12
\]
\end{document}
```

Using LuaLaTeX version 1.0.4, you get the following two renderings--Stix2 on the left and Computer Modern on the right (obtained by commenting out the `STIX2Math.otf` import).

[image: STIX2]
[image: Computer Modern]

The additional spacing between between the bar in the textstyle fractions seem undesirable.  What I haven't figured out yet is if this is an OpenType math specification problem, or a STIX2 problem.  I doubt it's a LuaLaTeX problem since my personal implementation of this algorithm gave similar results.

Comment: Do you mean Latin Modern Math is on the right? It's not going to be Computer Modern, is it?

Comment: @cfr actually I'm not sure.  I _thought_ lualatex defaulted to Computer Modern, but it might be Latin Modern Math.  I should use this for comparison instead.

Comment: @cfr I tried it with `latinmodern-math.otf` and got results similar (exact?) to the one on the right.  So this answers my question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tune the correct `\Umath` parameters.  See the LuaTeX manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
$\frac12$
\Umathfractionnumup    \textstyle=1ex
\Umathfractiondenomdown\textstyle=1ex
$\frac12$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've had problems with this approach, as the `\Umath…` parameters get reset if the font is reloaded (or something like that). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385715/1424) for a different method: Patching the font with a lua hook.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the specific parameters.  I feel like this might be a bug in STIX2.