# Unhappy with automatic bracket sizing using unicode-math and Libertinus

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, libertinus

I recently switched to the `Libertius` font familiy (available from [GitHub](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus)) for consistent text and math fonts. However, the automatic size calculation using `\left` and `\right` is not to my taste in all instances.

For example, in the following output, the square brackets seem too small, as they do not even reach at least up to the top and bottom edges of the content:

[image]

However, the norm seem way too big for the content.

As counterexample, see the following output *without* the `Libertinus` fonts set:

[image]

Can I get this with `Libertinus`?

Here's the MWE to produce above result (note that it only works if the `Libertinus` fonts are installed):

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
    \setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
    \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
%    \setmathfont[range={"02016}]{Latin Modern Math} % Replace \Vert

\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}

% macros for underscores of vectors
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\underline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
\newcommand{\uubar}[1]{\ubar{\ubar{#1}}}

% macros for bold symbols of vectors
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\symbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\vvec}[1]{\ubar{\symbfup{#1}}}
\newcommand{\vmat}[1]{\uubar{\symbfup{#1}}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        x &= \frac{3}{\sigma^y_{\gamma}} \left[ \frac{(1-z)g(z)}{2E} \right] \\
        y &= \norm{\vvec{r}_{\vec{\sigma}}(\vvec{\sigma}_{n+1,j+1})} \\
        \vvec{b} &= \vmat{A}\vvec{x}
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** I tried to replace the `\Vert` character with the one from the `XITS Math` font which did fix the size of the norms. However, this messes up the double underlines from my `\uubar` macro making the spacing way too big (see updated example). I don't really know what `\underline` might have to do with that...

**Update 2:** The `\Vert` can be fixed most easily for my needs by replacing the glyph with the corresponding one from the `Latin Modern Math` font: `\setmathfont[range={"02016}]{Latin Modern Math}`

[image]

Comment: You can to patch the font like here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385117/2388. But imho a bug report at the libertinus site is the better idea, the \Vert size look rather unbalanced.

Comment: Judging from the amount of open issues on the repo I don't expect this to be addressed too soon. I'll file a report anyways, but considering the time constrains, I'd probably better look for a substitute font then.